# Attaching two memory databases

Tags: sqlite

I am collecting data every second and storing it in a ":memory" database. Inserting data into this database is inside a transaction.

Everytime one request is sending to server and server will read data from the first memory, do some calculation, store it in the second database and send it back to the client. For this, I am creating another ":memory:" database to store the aggregated information of the first db. I cannot use the same db because I need to do some large calculation to get the aggregated result. This cannot be done inside the transaction( because if one collection takes 5 sec I will lose all the 4 seconds data). I cannot create table in the same database because I will not be able to write the aggregate data while it is collecting and inserting the original data(it is inside transaction and it is collecting every one second)

-- Sometimes I want to retrieve data from both the databses. How can I link both these memory databases? Using attach database stmt, I can attach the second db to the first one. But the problem is next time when a request comes how will I check the second db is exist or not?

-- Suppose, I am attaching the second memory db to first one. Will it lock the second database, when we write data to the first db?

-- Is there any other way to store this aggregated data??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got your idea, I don't think that you need two databases at all. I suppose you are misinterpreting the idea of transactions in sql.

If you are beginning a transaction other processes will be still allowed to read data. If you are reading data, you probably don't need a database lock.

**A possible workflow could look as the following.**

1. Insert some data to the database (use a transaction just for the
   insertion process)
2. Perform heavy calculations on the database (but do not use a transaction, otherwise it will prevent other processes of inserting any data to your database). Even if this step includes really heavy computation, you can still insert and read data by using another process as `SELECT` statements will not lock your database.
3. Write results to the database (again, by using a transaction)

Just make sure that heavy calculations are not performed within a transaction.

If you want a more detailed description of this solution, look at the documentation about the file locking behaviour of sqlite3: http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html